# KeyChain Access and GPG Keychain - should those be running simultaneously?

Tags: keychain, gpg

I have installed GPG Suite and found out also during this time that my OS X has some app that stores all my passwords under my screenlock password - total news to me.  Can I get rid of Apple app if I now have GPG? Really need help with this Apple app.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You have no reason to remove Keychain Access and doing so would break important parts of the OS.

Comment: Given that it is dependent on one single user password, I do not want to use it.  It's terrible security.  What can I do?